# Java Socket doesn't wait to receive bytes

Tags: java, sockets

I have developed a socket in java like this:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

System.out.println("Listening in port " + port + " ...");

while (true) {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Connection has been created.");
    handle(socket);
}
```

And the `handle` method is:

```
private static void handle(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                MyClass elevator = new MyClass(socket, is);
                elevator.start();
            } catch (IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And MyClass is like this:

```
class MyClass {

    private Socket socket;
    private InputStream is;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private OutputStream ds;

    public MyClass(Socket socket, InputStream is) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.is = is;
        initializeOutputStream(socket);
    }

    private void initializeOutputStream(Socket socket) {
        try {
            ds = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start() {

        while (true) {
            try {

                int dataLength = 10;
                byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[dataLength];
                is.read(dataBuffer, 0, dataLength);
                // Read and Print cmd.
                System.out.println("data:" + DataLayer.byteToString(dataBuffer));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    ds.close();
                    System.out.println("ds closed.");
                    is.close();
                    System.out.println("is closed.");
                    socket.close();
                    System.out.println("socket closed.");
                    break;
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the client sends data it works well, but when the client isn't sending data it prints:

```
data:0

data:0

data:0
...
```

and it dont stops.

Can you tell me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: What does `is.read` return?

Answer (score 1):

The situation you described happens when the connection is closed by the client-side (i.e. socket closed/stream at the end), and **not** when simply the client is not sending anything (if the client is idle but still connected, the server does not print anything).

And this is because the method `read` of the `InputStream` class does **not** throw an exception when the stream/connection is closed, but simply return the value `-1`, so with your implementation, the while loop simply continues to run infinitely.

Therefore a quick fix of this issue can be to replace the line where you read the stream with these two:

```
int endOfStream=is.read(dataBuffer, 0, dataLength);
if(endOfStream==-1) break;
```

Basically in this way you are checking if the stream is closed: if this is the case, break the while loop.

Another solution could be to declare and initialize the variable `int endOfStream=0;` before the while loop, and change the while loop condition in this way:

```
int endOfStream = 0; //init to 0 to enter a first time in the loop
while (endOfStream != -1) { //new loop condition
    try {
        int dataLength = 10;
        byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[dataLength];
        endOfStream = is.read(dataBuffer, 0, dataLength); //store the return of read
        if (endOfStream != -1) { //check if we are not at the end of the stream
            // Read and Print cmd.
            System.out.println("data:" + dataBuffer[0]);
        }
//... the rest of your code ...
```

Another issue in your code is what I guess is a bug, but I'm not sure because otherwise you shouldn't be able to run your code (but I can not say, since your copied code is not complete). The bug is when you call the start method `MyClass.start();`: since this method is not static, you must call it on the object of the class `MyClass` that you instantiated the line before, i.e. call the method in this way: `elevator.start();`

I hope this may help you.

Comment: 'endOfStream' is a strange name for a variable that holds either a read count or an end of stream *indicator* value. It isn't a Boolean.

Comment: Thnx Enne,

I'm sorry, actually it's elevator.start();

I tried you code 

    if(is.read(dataBuffer, 0, dataLength) == -1) break;

Now I'll check if it's working ok.

Comment: @EJP you're right, but it was just to be super-clear with the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
int something = is.read(dataBuffer, 0, dataLength);
if(something ==-1)
  break; 
else
  System.out.println("data:" + DataLayer.byteToString(dataBuffer));
```